# swapping out nav to a range slider nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a biology teacher and want to build a web page featuring dinosaur fossils/etc... taken from a 360 perspective. Students would then be able to examine the fossils by rotating them around.

Our programming guru is on sabbatical and I feel like Bones on classic Star Trek, "Damn it Jim! I'm a doctor, not a computer!"

I have 16 photos that I'd like to rotate--I found an example here: https://github.com/orangium/LivePx

I'd like to slide/rotate using a slider like this one: http://rangeslider.js.org

When I try to modify the player.js from the LivePx project I get a bunch of prototype errors--can someone tell me which file I should be looking at if player.js and playerUI.js aren't the correct files to modify?

Thanks!

Comment: `console` should display line number of error. Can you include `html`, `css`, `javascript` that you have tried at Question? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Prototype errors are VERY generic, but typically relate to object extensions (as in trying to extend an object that has not been instantiated yet). Since you have not provided the specific errors you are receiving, the best advice we can provide at this point is to take a look at the errors, grab the line numbers of the errors (and the actual error messages)  from the console and update your answer with the additional data.